# WebView + GPS in sleep mode or locked screen Android

Tags: android, webview, gps, background-application, service-application

i am starting in Android dev. I have a web page, this can take the latitude and longitude from html5 apis. But... i need to take gps info with locked screen (sleep mode). 
I think, that a good idea to start is to make an application with a WebView who keep the GPS on while the screen is locked. 
I had read something like a "service" but i don`t know how it work.
It this a good method?
How i can do this?

Thanks.